# Created a cron job in wordpress But the logs are displayed only when someone visits the page

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

In wordpress, I have worked to create a cron job.Currently, The Cron job displays the logs only when somebody visits the page. But, i want it to run without any page visit. I know that can be done. But how , that is what i dont know. Please guide me friends. I have used the function wp_scheduled_event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. Wordpress crons are not server crons, they depend of PHP to be executed, so it'll run only if someone visit your website.

From [`wp_schedule_event`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) documentation:

> The action will trigger when someone visits your WordPress site, if
>   the scheduled time has passed.

You'll need a server cron if you want to get through this limitation. Depends of your hosting, you may be able to configure a cron through the manager, or if you have SSH access on your server (so if it's not a shared hosting), execute this command :

```
crontab -e
```

It'll open your crontab file. Add this line inside to add a cron job:

```
*/30 * * * * php-cli -f /path/to/your/php/script.php
```

Replace with the correct path to your php script. This command will execute the script every 30 minutes - change this to whatever you need ([read more](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)).

If you're on a shared hosting and your manager doesn't allow you to create cron jobs, you could maybe use an online service like [this one](https://www.setcronjob.com/) to execute your script.